# NX - UI Library with Storybook and individually exported components

Tags: angular, storybook, nrwl, nrwl-nx, angular-storybook

I'm exploring Nx with Angular (relatively new to both) and trying to figure out how to generate a component library that:

- Can run Storybook, and
- Can be imported one component at a time, rather than dragging the whole module/all the components into an app that requires a single component. (To avoid adding unnecessary code/bloat to my bundle).

So the ideal setup is sort of like this:

```
repo
 |--apps
    |--normal-app (can import just card or button, without pulling in both)
 |--libs
    |--ui (lists individually exportable components, and has a servable Storybook)
       |--.storybook
       |--card
       |--button
```

Following both a general Nx tutorial that showed how to create a shared component lib, as well as the guide for setting up [Storybook in Nx](https://nx.dev/angular/plugins/storybook/overview), I generated a UI lib, and set up a Storybook schematic (if that's the right way to say it) for that lib directory.

The hope was to have all my shared components in one lib, and have Storybook set up to autogenerate and serve stories for each component -- but then be able to individually pull components from that lib into other applications *without* pulling in the whole, bulky UI library.

I successfully built out a UI lib and two components in it. I successfully set up Storybook in that lib. I then imported the `UIModule` from the `index.ts` file (the public API) in the UI lib, and used one of the two components in my template.

But then when I built the app that was importing the lib, the production build contained *both* components, although I had used one. This makes sense, since I'm importing the `UiModule`. This is, however, non-ideal.

I'm hoping to create a setup that allows for collocated components in a lib with Storybook setup, which can be imported *individually*.

Is there a way to do this without drastically altering the NX setup? I've explored two main options so far. One is to break all the components into their own UI libs, import them all into a separate app that is set up for Storybook, and import them individually into a main app. Like this (attempt #1):

```
repo
 |--apps
    |--storybook-app (imports all)
    |--other-app (imports just button)
 |--libs
    |--button
    |--card
```

That's non-ideal, though, for several reasons:

- It doesn't group the components.
- It involves a lot more lib boilerplate.
- It doesn't autogenerate stories for each component.
- It requires devs to remember to add a story to the Storybook for each component.

As a second attempt (#2), I tried to generate each of the components as separate libs in a shared directory:

```
repo
 |--apps
    |--storybook-app (imports all)
    |--other-app (imports just button)
 |--libs
    |--ui (just a directory; not a "project")
      |--button (module; has separate component dir beneath)
      |--card
```

This has a number of drawbacks of its own:

- Still can't autogenerate stories.
- Unclear where my Storybook should be. Is it a self-standing app, as in the above tree diagram? That seems non-idiomatic. I tried to put it in the `ui` directory, but since that's not a "project", I get a `Cannot find project 'ui'` when I attempt to do so using the VSCode NX extension.
- I have to generate both a lib and a component within a lib for each UI component. This is extra boilerplate and extra code and extra opportunity for mistakes.
- It seems to me that the Storybook should not be an app, since it can be served normally, but has its own serving commands.

I could build out one of the versions described above (#2, probably), but I suspect there are best practices for what seems like a common use case. It seems that much of my confusion stems from the Angular dependency-injection. (In a React app, you could just import a component, but in Angular, each component belongs to a module and that, specifically, needs to be injected as well. Is it a bad practice to have component-specific modules?)

Does anyone know of an idiomatic/best-practice way to meet these ideal specifications (shared storybook library with individual exported components, or split components with automatically generated stories in NX)?

Comment: How do you feel about the accepted answer after using it for more than a year?

Comment: Ended up going in a completely different direction, because of a change in client specs, so can't really say, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi. I found out that when developing component libraries, you must use sub-entrypoints (eg. `import { } from '@example/mylib/navbar';`) or else, as you're stating, loading a single module from the library drags your entire library into the main bundle. I managed to reduce my main bundle from 970kB to 501kB by using sub-entrypoints in my library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found a totally satisfactory solution for this problem, but here's what I ended up doing. It's close to #2 above:

1. Created a `libs/ui` directory (not a project)
2. Built a generator script that creates each component as its own separate module within that directory, and auto-creates a story scaffold in it.
3. Created a `component-lib` lib. (Rather than an app, because Storybook has its own separate run commands).
4. Set up a Storybook config in there using the Nx CLI.
5. Altered the Storybook config to grab *all* `.stories.ts` files under the `libs/ui` directory.

That way, the `component-lib` directory automatically adds each new component as its added, and I don't have to worry about a bunch of boilerplate whenever I add a component. Also, each component can be individually imported, without dragging in the bundle.

I won't share my whole component-generator script, but it's a basic JS file that

1. Runs the Nx library generator to generate a lib within the `ui` dir
2. Runs the Nx component generator to generate a component within that lib.
3. Uses `fs` to write an appropriate `.stories.ts` file in that lib.

Then, in my `component-lib` directory, I modified the final line in `.storybook/config.js` to require *all* stories under the `ui` lib:

```js
configure(require.context('../../ui', true, /\.stories\.tsx?$/), module);
```

It all feels a little hacky, particularly the generator script. But it works!

Comment: How did you manage dependency graph? Doesn’t change in one component in component-lib will mark all apps as affected whether or not that app is using that component?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use your initial approach and generate a module (not a lib) for each component set (or even only one component) you want to provide. Then export all modules in your index.ts

A angular lib in nrwl/nx must contain at least one module (Exceptions are data-libs),  like your normal angular project must contain the app.module. But that doesn't mean that you cannot have multiple modules exportet throughout the lib. With multiple modules you can import them independently from your lib.

Example

```
import { module1 } from '@mylib'
import { module2 } from '@mylib'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution in NX doc https://nx.dev/storybook/overview-angular

Short step-by-step:

1. Install yarn https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install
2. Install storybook plugin
   `yarn add --dev @nrwl/storybook`
3. Generating Storybook Configuration
   `nx g @nrwl/angular:storybook-configuration project-name`
4. Run `nx run project-name:storybook`

Create `*stories.ts` near any component.

Don't forget to add links to story files to main.js and tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

Each component can have its own NgModule which will be exported from the index file. Standalone components can be exported this way too using their respective ts file

```
// index.ts

export * from './lib/components.module'
export * from './lib/footer/components1.module'
export * from './lib/social-media/component2.module'
export * from './lib/back-arrow/standalone-component1.component'
```